# Leaflet draw shapes and get the overlapped/included zipcodes

Tags: postgis, leaflet, postgresql

I am new to the GIS world but I have experience in programming. I am trying to build an app where users draw circles on a leaflet map and it returns the zipcodes "touched", but I think the right term is overlapped, by the circles.
I have a table in PostGIS where I have uploaded the US census zipcodes; the column to query is a geometry type which return something like this when transformed as
GeoJSON:

```
{"type":"MultiPolygon","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:4269"}},"coordinates":[[[[-64.903808,17.679739],[-64.903804,17.679763],[-64.903799,17.679801],[-64.903796,17.67988],[-64.903793,17.679919],[-64.903788,17.679997],[-64.90377,17.680077],[-64.903756,17.680154],[-64.903744,17.680199],[-64.903729,17.68024],[-64.9037,17.68031]...}
```

This is the table:
[image]

And this is an example of the map with a circle drawn where I console log its radius and center coordinates (lat, lng):

[image]

So far I have tried this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tl_2019_us_zcta510 AS b
WHERE ST_DWithin(b.geom,
  ST_Transform(
    ST_SetSrid(
      ST_MakePoint(lat_from_leaflet,lng_from_leaflet)
      ,4269)
    ,4269)
,radius_from_leaflet);
```

This isn't returning the correct zipcodes because when I try with a small circle, for example, it doesn't return any row, but I am expecting at least one row.

Comment: Geometry is created {X,Y} and latitude is a Y. It should be {lon,lat}

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

- almost everywhere in OGC supported environments, coordinate order is **`{X, Y} | {lon, lat}`**
- your radius seems to be given in *meter*, while `ST_DWithin` (as almost all functions in PostGIS) assume the **primary unit of the CRS of the given geometry** - which is *degree* for `EPSG:4269`! In order to calculate proximity with *meter* as reference unit you'd need to either use a suitable projection, or the `GEOGRAPHY` type with a defined geographic CRS; I assume here that the input values are referenced in `EPSG:4326`:

  ```
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    <table> AS t
  WHERE
    ST_DWithin(
      t.geom::GEOGRAPHY(GEOMETRY, 4269),
      ST_Transfrom(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(<lon>, <lat>), 4326), 4269)::GEOGRAPHY(GEOMETRY, 4269),
      <radius_in_meter>
    )
  ;
  ```

  You'd want to have this covered by an appropriate index:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX ON <table> USING GIST (( geom::GEOGRAPHY(GEOMETRY, 4269) ));
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! When I try to run the query I get this error: ERROR:  Invalid geometry type modifier: 4269
LINE 7:     t.geom::GEOGRAPHY(4269),
                    ^
SQL state: 22023  Do you have any advise how to debug this?

Comment: @RmCs Try adding the geometry type, e.g. `GEOGRAPHY(POINT, 4269)`

Comment: I tried this: SELECT
  *
FROM
  tl_2019_us_zcta510 AS t
WHERE
  ST_DWithin(
    t.geom::GEOGRAPHY(POINT, 4269),
    ST_Transfrom(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-73.94633531570436, 40.787819679697904), 4326), 4269)::GEOGRAPHY(4269),
    162
  ); but I got the same error. Do I need to install specific extensions? Many thanks!

Comment: @RmCs you need to specify the geometry type in both casts; if you are not sure which type your data is, use the generic `GEOMETRY` type (this is **not** the ***data** type* `GEOMETRY`!) - see my updated query above. [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/kaYnthJy) is a *db<>fiddle* showing some options for casts.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! One last question: how should I update the indexing query? I tried this: CREATE INDEX us_zcta_index
  ON tl_2019_us_zcta510
  USING GIST (geom::GEOGRAPHY(GEOMETRY, 4269); but I got this error ERROR:  syntax error at or near "::"
LINE 3:   USING GIST (geom::GEOGRAPHY(GEOMETRY, 4269);

Comment: @RmCs note how I wrapped the expression in *two* pairs of parenthesis - that is on purpose, you need double parens in this location! Looks like I missed one at the end, though...added them in.

Comment: @RmCs did this solve your question/problem? If so, consider accepting the answer. If not, what issues are you facing?